# How would I gather environment variables externally

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables

I have a Kubernetes cluster running a Docker image. My web app is containerized and uses an environment variable that changes every couple of days.

I am wondering if there is a way to externally store the variables or if I just have to enter the new variables and push a new image every couple of days?

Comment: ...in a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)?  As you've described it you don't want to be rebuilding the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the `Env` in a `configmap` and mount it on your `deployment`. Just rollout your deployment if you want to update the `Env`s in the `pod`s(containers).